# ordinal data, same subjects, different times between measures

Tags: ordinal-data

I'am doing research on a long-term satisfactory of a specific operation.

1. I want to visualize the ordinal response over time. I have 44 patients, so per subject lines might be a bit too much. Scale: Healed - Significantly improved - Improved - Same - Mildly Worse - Significantly worse.
2. While not all patients are asked with same time window for the "now" (e.g. patient 1 is operated in 1999 and asked today and patient 2 is operated in 2005 and asked now). I am wondering if there is a statistical test which might be of interest to describe the satisfactory "progress".

Hope you can help me!

edit: something like below  this might be an idea as vizualisation?! FYI: this are independent groups! And some kind of regression with all "operation dates" fixed on day one and then months post operation as continous variable and 5 point ordinal als independent? What do I need to take into account?

[image]

Comment: Are there lost to followup or expected missing data (since you added the "survival" tag)? Otherwise there are numerous questions related to the comparison of [pre-post measures using Likert-type items](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=likert+pre-post) on this site.

Comment: Hmm.. good one, I think survival is not the best tag... better to delete it! in this case its not pre post but post post ;-)!

Comment: Pre-post was just an example, you can look for ordinal or likert + repeated measures or longitudinal keywords. Is time period a critical element, i.e. operations from 2000 are more likely to be judged severely than those carried out after, say, 2015?

Comment: I assume time is critical in another way, reoccurence of complaints. We assume that the satisfactory decreases over time (therefore I added the survival tag)

Comment: You have 44 patients, but your graph seems detailed (the position of the distinction between the ordinal categories is not very discretized).... Are you asking these patients every month about their satisfaction?

Comment: Sorry, this was a google example.. I'll try making a quick one regarding my data

Comment: Edit: now with data

Comment: There is not much trend to see in the current graph. And it is not very clear what numbers/counts the proportions represent. Hence, a table might be more informative.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *not all patients are asked with same time window for the "now"*. You also write that one patient is asked today and the other patient is asked now, is that a difference?

Comment: To sum up, this not a pre-post setup (subjects are not measured twice), and what you are really interested in is how average satisfaction evolved over time, taking into account the time elapsed between the intervention and survey. Is that correct?